# Extraer los registros que sean máximos de una lista de clientes en R

Tags: r

Buen día, tengo una base de clientes con el saldo de las cuentas en diferentes meses del año, pero necesito solamente los registros que tengan el valor máximo de estos saldos. He intentado con Apply de la siguiente forma pero no salen los resultados.

```
apply(data, 1, which.max(data$saldo))
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido @Diego Millan a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema con el uso de la función `apply`, con ésta aplicas otra función por cada fila, pero `which.max(saldo)` es un valor (el valor máximo de saldo de todo el `data.frame`) no una función, lo sería si hicieras algo así: `apply(data, 1, which.max)`, pero esto solo te retornará la columna con el valor máximo de cada fila, tampoco nos sirve. Lo que necesitas es trabajar por grupos, para esto hay otras alternativas:

Con un `data.frame` como el que comentas:

```
data <- data.frame(id=1:6,
                   mes=c(1,3,1,1,2,3), 
                   saldo=c(4,3,3,4,5,1))
```

Con R base, podrías resolverlo mediante:

```
merge(
    aggregate(saldo ~ mes, data, max),
    data
)
  mes saldo id
1   1     4  1
2   1     4  4
3   2     5  5
4   3     3  2
```

Con `aggregate(saldo ~ mes, data, max)` obtenemos un `data.frame` con el valor máximo de `saldo` por `mes`, luego simplemente lo combinamos con el `data.frame` original para así obtener todas las filas que correspondan: en un mismo mes podrías tener más de una fila si estás tienen el mismo valor de `saldo`.

Sino, como alternativa, si estas familiarizado con `dplyr`, sino te lo recomiendo, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
    group_by(mes) %>%    # Agrupamos por mes
    top_n(1, saldo) %>%  # Optenemos las filas de cada mes icon el máximo saldo
    arrange(mes)         # Ordenamos por mes

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   mes [3]
     id   mes saldo
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     4
2     4     1     4
3     5     2     5
4     2     3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu base de datos este en formato de data frame, se llame `df` y tengas 2 columnas llamadas `saldos` y `meses`, utilizando `dplyr` puedes usar:

```
df %>% group_by(meses) %>% summarise(saldos = max(saldos))
```

Lo que haces es primero agrupar el data frame por meses, y luego obtienes el saldo mayor para cada uno de estos meses

Te recomiendo poner ejemplos de tus bases de datos, o de una base de datos similar y el resultado esperado para una mayor claridad de la pregunta.

Saludos!